# Socket.io "on" function - pass additional parameters

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I can't find a nice way to pass additional parameters to socket.io 'on' handler, i.e.:

```
var someEventHandler = require('someEventHandler'),
    additionalData = {test: 1};
socket.on('event', someEventHandler);
```

Now I want to access additionalData object inside someEventHandler function which is located in another file. Is there a similar way to pass arguments to handlers like jQuery 'on' gives us? ( `$obj.on('event', '.selector', dataObject, handlerFunction)` )

Answer (score 4):

You can use another function to handle the event, which then passes whatever additional data you need.  Example:

```
var someEventHandler = require('someEventHandler'),
    additionalData = {test: 1};
socket.on('event', function(e) { someEventHandler(e, additionalData); } );
```

Comment: Yes I know this way but it seems ugly to me and I thought there really should be something like jQuery 'on' gives us.

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't like wrapping the callback yourself, you can change the `socket.on` function to make it match your desires. Something like

```
const originalOn = socket.on;
socket.on = function (event, data, callback) {
    return originalOn.call(socket, event, (e) => callback(e, data));
};
```

You can now use it like so:

```
let data = {/* important data */};
socket.on('importantEvent', data, (e, additionalData) => {
    // Have fun with your data
});
```